# kotlin , Creating an arraylist out of an arrayObject

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, kotlin

Trying to make an Arraylist out of my obbjects, using the ArrayList of below code . 
Here my code is :-

```
       var i = 1.0
    var list: ArrayList<Any> = ArrayList()
    while (i <= n) {
        intPerMonth = P * R
        P = P - (e - intPerMonth)
        Log.e("TAG", "Month -> " + i.toInt())
        Log.e("TAG", "Interest per month -> " + Math.round(intPerMonth))
        Log.e("TAG", "Principal per month -> " + Math.round(e - intPerMonth))
        Log.e("TAG", "Balance Principal -> " + Math.round(P))
        Log.e("TAG", "***************************")

        list = arrayListOf(
            i.toInt(),
            Math.round(intPerMonth),
            Math.round(e - intPerMonth),
            Math.round(e - intPerMonth),
            Math.round(P)
        )
        i++
        Log.e("myArray", list.toString()) // this list.toString() is my output

    }
```

Output of this Program is

`E/myArray: [1, 10, 79, 79, 921]
 E/myArray: [2, 9, 80, 80, 842]
E/myArray: [3, 8, 80, 80, 761]`

but i want this type of list:-

```
[(1,10,79,79,921),(2,9,80,80,842),(3,8,80,80,761)]
```

Comment: try using ArrayList<ArrayList> type

Comment: this is kotlin bro @AlesandroGiordano

Comment: can you explain in coding? @AlesandroGiordano

Comment: Yes excuse me, I'll try to simulate it in a console.. wait a moment

Comment: ok sure , thank you @AlesandroGiordano

Comment: i've answered your problem?

Comment: i got my answer from google searching , thank you for helping me @AlesandroGiordano

Comment: Rate my answer if is the souction that you have found, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you want a list of lists? Try creating an inner list in every iteration that you then add to your list, like this:

```
var i = 1.0
var list: ArrayList<Any> = ArrayList()
while (i <= n) {
    intPerMonth = P * R
    P = P - (e - intPerMonth)
    Log.e("TAG", "Month -> " + i.toInt())
    Log.e("TAG", "Interest per month -> " + Math.round(intPerMonth))
    Log.e("TAG", "Principal per month -> " + Math.round(e - intPerMonth))
    Log.e("TAG", "Balance Principal -> " + Math.round(P))
    Log.e("TAG", "***************************")

    var innerList = arrayListOf( // create a different list here
        i.toInt(),
        Math.round(intPerMonth),
        Math.round(e - intPerMonth),
        Math.round(e - intPerMonth),
        Math.round(P)
    )
    list.add(innerList) // add the inner list to your list
    i++
}
Log.e("myArray", list.toString()) // this prints the new list of lists
```